# How to manipulate controller's scope from directive in angular 1.4.5+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i overwrite the myCtrl's variable from directive?
and after, the controller must update the results...

I heard about bindToController, but I could not get it to work.

Used ng version 1.4.5

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST">
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(field, value) in box.fields">
            <div class="my-toggle" my-toggle="field" ng-bind="value['par2']"></div>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
//The question is, how can i overwrite the myCtrl's variable from directive?
//and after, the controller must update the results...

//I heard about bindToController, but I could not get it to work.

//used version 1.4.5

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope){
    $scope.box = {
        fields : {
            fieldOne:{
                par1 : 10,
                par2 : 12,
            },
            fieldTwo:{
                par1 : 20,
                par2 : 24,
            },
            fieldThree:{
                par1 : 30,
                par2 : 36,
            }
        }
    };
});

myapp.directive('myToggle', [function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myToggle : '=',  
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attr){
        var startX = 0, x = 0;
        var elementLeft = 0;

        element.on('mousedown', function(event){
            //ctrlSCOPE.fields[scope.mytoggle]['par1'] + 1;
            //console.log(ctrlSCOPE.fields[scope.mytoggle]['par2']);
        });
    },
  };
}]);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLvqxuoL/5/) - Illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to think of `bindToController` that gets used when `controllerAs` syntax is used in directive.

I think you should pass `value` of `ng-repeat` instead of passing its key `field` like `my-toggle="value"`

As you are going to update a scope variable from `mousedown` event, which wouldn't update value of scope variable. Events are considered as out of angular context, thus angular doesn't run digest cycle for such case. You could run that digest cycle by doing `scope.$apply()`. Better would be `$timeout` which will avoid the `digest` cycle conflict.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="(field, value) in box.fields">
    <div class="my-toggle" my-toggle="value" ng-bind="value['par2']"></div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
myapp.directive('myToggle', [function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        myToggle : '='
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attr){
        var startX = 0, x = 0;
        var elementLeft = 0;

        element.on('mousedown', function(event){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.myToggle['par1'] = scope.myToggle['par1'] + 1;
            scope.myToggle['par2'] = scope.myToggle['par2'] + 1;
            console.log(scope.myToggle['par2']);
          });
        });
    },
  };
}]);
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld0bpvaL/)

Comment: or use `ng-mousedown` and skip the $apply

Comment: @charlietfl absolutely correct..so that can go in controller.